# python: selecting part of a gaussian fit curve of a histogram for analysis

Tags: python, histogram, distribution, gaussian, curve

I have a set of histograms for various sets of data. I have fit curves to the data using the code below and receive bell shaped curves. I would like to do two things: 
1. sub-select part of that data for further analysis based on where it falls in the histogram with relation to the curve (i.e. take all values that fall between the peak of the bell curve and halfway between the peak and the end of the curve and move that to a new vector for analysis). 
2. draw vertical lines on the plotted histogram designating the start and stop of the included areas.

[image: current histogram] 
[image: desired histogram and selection]

```
tempCirc=circ_total1[:,30]
statsG.append(lister+" Tubule Diameter="+str(np.mean(tempCirc))+" stdev="+str(np.std(tempCirc)))
diameter_Glob.append(np.mean(tempCirc))
plt.hist(tempCirc,bins=100,normed=True)
plt.xlim((min(tempCirc), max(tempCirc)))
mean = np.mean(tempCirc)
variance = np.var(tempCirc)
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)
xtemp = np.linspace(min(tempCirc), max(tempCirc),100)
plt.plot(xtemp,mlab.normpdf(xtemp,mean,sigma))
```

Comment: What are you calling the "end of the curve"? The standard definition of the normal distribution bell curve has no end - the tails are infinite (but infinitely decreasing - they just never actually reach zero). The "peak" of the curve is also known as the mean of the population.

Comment: I guess I would have to set a threshold for angle of the curve and when it approaches somewhere close to flat define that as the start/end..if I could vectorize the curve I guess I could do a for x in range (0,length(curve)) if (x-(x+1))<=somethreshold...x=end

Comment: A more "normal" way would be to look at data within a number of "standard deviations" from the mean...

Comment: Yup that makes more sense. Thanks!